# Matlab cftool can't see all my environment vectors

Tags: matlab, curve-fitting

I've used the interactive curve fitting tool before without problems. But now I've set up a workspace with all the vectors I'll need for my x and y values (I plan to make 6 fits total). But when I go to "data" in the cftool GUI, all that is available in the drop boxes for both x and y are 3 of my vectors (the ones I intend to use as x values) - it's missing all the 6 vectors I plan to use as y values.

I've tried closing and restarting the GUI multiple times with no luck. It seems from my workspace that all the vectors are the same size. I don't know why cftool can't see them all - any ideas?

Comment: What happens if you open cftool with cftool(x,y) where y is one of the missing vectors?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out, and in case this question comes up in a search, it was that the vectors I wanted were singles and I needed to convert them to doubles. I forgot to use "whos" to check the type of all my vectors.